Bypass the need for a service layer with SQL Server views (for Read Only)
A service interface allows a service layer to support backwards compatibility.  As long as the different versions of the API are still supported, then changes can be added to the newer versions of the API.
I am getting pushback on this concept, saying that SQL Server views provide the same capability.  The idea is that a direct connection to a Microservice's database is OK as long as view is used.  This is because any needed changes can be made backwards compatible via the view.  This allows for better performance for larger result sets and also removes the need to call a service in technologies that do not handle that well.
This feels wrong to me.  The main reason I can come up with is Security.  But while not ideal, SQL Server's security can be made to fill in here.  A side reason is a lot of clutter as many views start to show up.
But aside from those issues, I am unsure the exact reason why.  (But I feel sure that a Microservice architecture requires that the database be protected by the service.)
Here are some reasons that I have found do not apply to read only situations:

Business Logic (All my business logic is done on the way into the database.)
Validation (Again, the validation is done on the way into the database)
Security (As I said above, this is a good one, but SQL Server's security can be made to work.)

So this is my question:  What are the actual reasons that connecting to a service layer is better than directly querying a SQL Server View for read operations?

You're asking the wrong question, there is no absolute "right" and "wrong". Instead try and think in terms of the trade offs of each approach

The biggest problem I see is busting right through the separation and independence that a micro services architecture is supposed to give you.

If one service connects directly to the database of another service, then you introduce possibilities of deploying incompatible changes to your views, which break the other services.
Now your micro services are no longer independently deployable unless you can absolutely guarantee that changes to the views are backwards compatible.

You introduce another point of failure for those other micro services. If the shared database goes down or runs slow, other micro services will start running slow. This cascade effect is the worst part of Service Oriented Architecture, and your are willfully sneaking this into what should be a resilient architecture.
This means your services are no longer independently scalable. Traffic from one service has a direct impact on another service, even when that service is not in use.

These database views can start growing hairs from the other applications. Their needs start sneaking into another micro service. This just adds to the coupling between services, thus breaking the independently deployable part.


Basically, the "independently deployable and scalable" criteria for micro services is completely broken, rendering your infrastructure little more than a distributed monolith or old school Service-Oriented Architecture (and all the disadvantages that come with it).
On the other hand, it would be simpler until the first production issue arises...

You probably wont win this argument on technical grounds. An SQL server can implement an api layer with views and sprocs etc.
I would take a security, testing and deployment approach

How do you do your security audits? now you have to include both api users and sql users. Who is managing this? Do you need row or column level security? Is the firewall open on the sql port? will the passwords be rotated?

Who is responsible for maintaining these views and ensuring zero downtime deployments? Decommisioning old versions etc

How are you testing these views? Where are the unit tests going and how are they run on builds


It's not that these things cant be done on the view, but it highlights the non functional features you get with an api that people don't think about when they just want to "do a select".

Mainstream client-server SQL engines already provide the full facilities of a service, and are extremely well-refined technology, so there is no general reason to employ an additional layer if a direct connection will do.
Security
The main problem with security on SQL engines is that they take some expertise to configure correctly and keep correct. The surface area is large and diverse on account of the full capabilities of the engine.
The underlying age of the engines means there can be signs of the design having been updated within legacy constraints, rather than designed from a clean slate, which adds to the complexity of understanding.
And client-server SQL engines are ultimately designed to cope with the needs of the biggest corporations with the most complexity and the most technical staff, and the security system is therefore somewhat complex as the price of being highly flexible. This can sit badly with "full stack" (i.e. one-man-band) developers where security needs may be quite simple and the initial learning curve severe.
The end result is that own-rolled approaches to security can be preferred, which might not maintain well or may have subtle holes when it comes to determined adversaries, but where the solo developer feels more in control at the outset.
Network connections
Perceived problems may arise when a particular network configuration means that a direct SQL connection is difficult or impossible to achieve, or where a business has accumulated a variety of storage technologies with no standard connection method.
There may then be a desire to reduce everything to a common denominator like HTTP and JSON. This is often wildly inefficient relative to native drivers and protocols, but in some contexts it may at least present a more consistent and generic interface into the various data stores.
Validation and business logic
There is often no division of labour between the person writing the server-side code in SQL and the person writing the client-side code in another general purpose programming language.
The web has also introduced an additional middle layer on the server side which generates the web page, which is often also coded in one or more GP programming languages.
There can therefore be a desire to consolidate on one language as much as possible, and if the person has weak SQL skills then the SQL engine is relegated to doing the minimum amount.
Certain approaches to testing and deployment can also reconcile poorly with the use of the SQL engine.
In general though, the mix of different problems that get caused or solved by each approach, and the wide variety of circumstances which may apply to each application, means it's largely a matter of taste or a professional judgement made in a specific context.

My $0.02 after thinking on this for a bit. SQL Server cannot support modern authorization protocols like OAuth 2 or modern authentication protocols like OIDC.  It is very difficult to build a SQL Server based application without a service layer to convert current style security into what SQL Server can support.

@Vaccano, I'm not sure what SQL Server might support with Azure, but you're right that special authentication schemes not handled natively, are a reason for another layer.
